# Convert (project) 3D points onto 2D image plane

Tags: ros, transform

I am working with several TF frames (attached to my robot) and their corresponding 3D coordinates. These frames are positioned within the camera's field of view, specifically in the honey/nav_cam topic, which eliminates the need for the extrinsic matrix.

The honey/nav_cam (camera) topic is responsible for capturing images. My objective is to project (convert) the 3D points, originally in the camera frame, onto these images. As a result, I will obtain 2D pixel coordinates within the images.

I have known camera parameters: an intrinsic matrix and a single distortion coefficient, indicating a FOV distortion model.

In the provided image, you can see accurate projections of the 3D points when the robot is centered in the camera frame (in the center of the image):

[image: Accurate projection]

"Corresponding" picture from the simulation with the tf frames (as RGB tubes):

[image]

The precision of the projection is lost when my robot (tf frames) is not in the center of the image (and even worse towards the edges):

[image]

My conversion 3D (points in meter) into 2D (in pixels) is as follows:

```
def project_3d_to_2d_fov(point):# point is of 3 values: x, y, z (z is the distance)
# The intrinsic matrix and distortion coefficient
intrinsic_matrix = np.array([
  [607.64218, 0.0, 640],
  [0.0, 606.53899, 480],
  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
])

dist_coeff = 0.99872
# Assume that the 3D point is in the camera coordinate system,
# so we don't need extrinsic parameters.

# Normalize the point (remove the effect of the focal length and principal point)
x, y, z = point

# To obtain the perspective-corrected co-ordinates
x_norm = x / z
y_norm = y / z

# Apply FOV distortion
r = np.sqrt(x_norm**2 + y_norm**2)
theta = np.arctan(r)
theta_d = np.arctan(2 * np.tan(dist_coeff / 2) * np.tan(theta / 2))
scale = theta_d / r if r != 0 else 1.0  # To handle r=0
# Applies the scaling factor to get the distorted coordinates.
x_distorted = x_norm * scale
y_distorted = y_norm * scale

# Convert normalized coordinates back to pixel coordinates
# https://community.stereolabs.com/t/from-3d-point-to-2d-pixel/517
fx, fy = intrinsic_matrix[0, 0], intrinsic_matrix[1, 1]
cx, cy = intrinsic_matrix[0, 2], intrinsic_matrix[1, 2]

u = x_distorted * fx + cx
v = y_distorted * fy + cy

return [u, v]
```

Please help with the precision of the projection and also tell me what could be wrong.
Thank you in advise.